# Jasmine: Unit test http service error observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am pretty confused on how to mock that my http service catches an observable error. I have read through the angular documentation but I do not understand how I would structure the test. I would like to mock an error in my service, then check that it catches an error observable. I have another service that creates and throws the error observable. The rest of my services just catch it when encountering an error. I am honestly very confused on how to implement this. Here is a simple verison of my service, and also the error service:

```
getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url)
       .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
}

  handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}
```

Now how would I simulate an error? Do I need to spy on the service and make it fail? Would something along the lines of `spyOn(service, 'getData).and.returnValue(Observable.throw({status: 404})))` or am I looking at this the wrong way? Thanks.

EDIT: Code with  Castro Roy's solution.

```
import {HttpErrorResponse, } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing'
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing'
import {HttpService} from '../services/http.service'

fdescribe('MyService', () => {
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [HttpService]
        });
        httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });

    afterEach(() => {

        httpTestingController.verify();
    });

    it('should be created', inject([HttpService], (service: HttpService)=> {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));

    it('should handleErrorObservable', inject([HttpService], (service: HttpService) => {
        const urlString = '/data';
        const emsg = 'deliberate 404 error';

        spyOn(service, 'handleErrorObservable').and.callThrough();

        service.getData(urlString).subscribe(
            data => fail('should have failed with the 404 error'),
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

              expect(service.handleErrorObservable).toHaveBeenCalled(); // check if executed

              expect(error.status).toEqual(404, 'status');
              expect(error.error).toEqual(emsg, 'message');

             });

        const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(urlString);


        req.flush(emsg, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found' });
      }));
});
```

Comment: As you are accessing the httpClient you should use the `HttpClientTestingModule` to test the http calls made. See here https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests and for error handling https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling .

Comment: Thank you. I did follow that documentation, but I am unsure how to adapt that to handling my errors. I did manage to test my services for the correct calls using HttpTestingController and my service. I guess it is kind of the same idea, expect I have to cause it to fail, then expect an observable to be thrown if it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`spyOn(service, 'getData').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({status: 404})))` migth be useful if you are trying to mock `getData` to some other service that use it, but `handleErrorObservable` will never be executed. So, if you want to test that `handleErrorObservable` have been called, something like this should help you:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { MyService } from './MyService';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [MyService]
    });

    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // After every test, assert that there are no more pending requests.
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should handleErrorObservable', inject([MyService], (service: MyService) => {
    const urlString = '/data';
    const emsg = 'deliberate 404 error';

    spyOn(service, 'handleErrorObservable').and.callThrough();

    service.getData(urlString).subscribe(
        data => fail('should have failed with the 404 error'),
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

          expect(service.handleErrorObservable).toHaveBeenCalled(); // check if executed

          expect(error.status).toEqual(404, 'status');
          expect(error.error).toEqual(emsg, 'message');
        }
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(urlString);

    // Respond with mock error
    req.flush(emsg, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found' });
  }));
});
```

Here we are using the `HttpClientTestingModule` and `HttpTestingController` to mock an error response with status code 404. Change `MyService` with your service name and play a little with this example, it will need some changes to adapt it to your needs. [More info in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests)

Also, take [a look to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948524/angular-unit-tests-typeerror-this-http-get-pipe-is-not-a-function) where are using a different way of mocking the `HttpClient` service.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I have a much better understanding. Now if my handleError was a private method, how would I spy on getData to catch handleErrorObservable? Would I have it check for an observable to ensure that when getData fails, it catches handleErrorObservable? Since it is private there would be no way of actually calling the service. Thank you.

Comment: We can not `spy` on a private method. You can update `getData` to take a second argument, the error callback function, then you can `spy` on that function though.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Would it be possible to check for the line `catch(this.handleErrorObservable)` from the getData service? In this situation, the method handleErrorObservable is private. Also, my apologies to throw in another question; when running the test you posted,  my service is successfully called, but `error.status and error.error` are undefined. I receive the error message stating `Expected undefined to equal 404`. Thank you!

Comment: No. But you can check that `getData` throw the error in your test. And this is already covered in the example I gave.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. So the provided example is already checking if an error is thrown with the line `service.getData(urlString).subscribe...`.

Comment: Correct, hope it helps

Comment: Yes thank you for clarification on the subject. My only issues as of now, is error.status and error.error are undefined. To my understanding these are from HttpErrorResponse, so I should not have to initialize them. I receive the error `Expected undefined to be 404` and vice versa for error.error when running both expect statements.

Comment: The 404 code and error are _mocked_ in the line `req.flush(emsg, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found' });`. Did you forget to add it?

Comment: No I did not, that is why I am scratching my head :/ I will update my question with the code in case I may be missing something.

Comment: Your problem is this line `return Observable.throw(error.message || error);`, change it to `return Observable.throw(error);`

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you. Was it failing because the test did not know what message was?

Comment: You were throwing only the message `error.message` and not the entire `error`