# Errors testing in HttpClient service

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm learning to test an Angular app with Jasmine and try to deal with my HttpClient service. All specs were executed successfully and  I want to simulate a situation when something goes wrong. I wrote a spec, but it is executed with such error **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"**. I don't understand, why I get this error and how to deal with it. 
Here is my spec:

```
describe('DataService', () => {
    let service: DataService;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [DataService]
        });

        // inject the service
        service = TestBed.get(DataService);
        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });   

    it('can test for server error', () => {
        service.createEmployee(MOCK_EMPLOYEE[0]).subscribe((response) => {
         fail('should not respond with new employee')
        },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                expect(error.error.status).toEqual(500);
            });

       let call: TestRequest = 
        httpMock.expectOne(`${service.baseUrl}/employees`);
        expect(call.request.method).toEqual('POST');
        call.error(
            new ErrorEvent('Server error'), { status: 500 }
        );
        httpMock.verify();
    });
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-for-errors, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse. `expect(error.error.status).toEqual(500);` should be `expect(error.status).toEqual(500);`.

Comment: Oh, it;s my fail ! But in this case I also get error : Expected undefined to equal 500

Comment: Again: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-for-errors: `req.flush(emsg, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found' });`. error() is for simaulting networking errors, when you don't even get a response from the server.

Comment: [This answer might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156450/jasmine-unit-test-http-service-error-observable/51164121#51164121)