# angular unit test function.pipe is not a function

Tags: angular

I am aware there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948524/angular-unit-tests-typeerror-this-http-get-pipe-is-not-a-function)

but I am doing what the suggested answer says and I am still getting this error

basically I have a function like so

```
checkForInvitation() {
        this._join.joinInformationSource.pipe(filter(x => x !== null)).subscribe(result => {
            this.joinInformation = result;
            this.setFields(result.userInfo);
        });
    }
```

basically it gets information and then calls another method to prepopulate some form fields.

now I am trying to test this method so I have created a spy like so...

```
// ...

const joinServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('JoinService', ['joinInformationSource']);

// ...

providers: [
    { provide: JoinService, useValue: joinServiceSpy }
]

// ...

joinService = TestBed.get(JoinService);

it('should prepopulate fields if there is join information', () => {
   let joinInfoSpy = joinService.joinInformationSource.and.returnValue(
       of(
          // ... object
       )
   )
});
```

now when I run ng test I get this error repeatedly

`this._join.joinInformationSource.pipe is not a function`

this is my joinService

```
joinInformationSource = new BehaviorSubject<JoinInformation>(null);

setJoinInformation(joinInformation: JoinInformation) {
    this.joinInformationSource.next(joinInformation);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Can you create a reproduction of this?

Comment: When is checkForInvitation() called? Inside the constructor/onInit or only on a template interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [createSpyObj](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/jasmine.html#.createSpyObj) accepts a list of methods as a second parameter. So when you're creating the mocking object, you create `joinInformationSource` as a function.

```
const joinServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('JoinService', ['joinInformationSource']);

//now joinSeverSpy contains method joinInformationSource
```

But in your code you use `joinInformationSource` as a field

```
// _join.joinInformationSource has been used as a field

this._join.joinInformationSource.pipe(filter(x => x !== null)).subscribe(result => {
    this.joinInformation = result;
    this.setFields(result.userInfo);
});
```

And since `joinInformationSource` is a function it definitely doesn't have a `pipe` method. There are few solutions. One of them is using of [spyOnProperty](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/global.html#spyOnProperty) method:

```
//create a service object and define a property

const joinService: any = new Object();
Object.defineProperty(joinService, 'joinInformationSource', {get: () => {}});

//then create a spy on the property

it('should prepopulate fields if there is join information', () => {
    let joinInfoSpy = spyOnProperty(joinService, 'joinInformationSource', 'get')
        .and.returnValue(
            new BehaviorSubject<JoinInformation>(//object)
        )
    }
    //the rest of the code
);
```

Comment: So how would i test this function??